# very old iPad 2's Youtube app won't update anymore

Tags: ipad

I just get stuck on "Tap to Retry" get a pop up box to update but it does not (forget exact sequence of the "stuck" loop.

What is like a nuclear option way to update Youtube app on old iPad 2?

I cannot play any videos on it now and it only shows Tap to Retry.

Comment: You might be in a situation that the literal current version of the YouTube is incompatible with your device. If that’s the case there is no way to install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPad 2 can be updated up to iOS 9.3.6 only, the current version of the YouTube app requires iOS/iPadOS 12 though. So you can‘t update the app on that iPad any longer.

You can try to use Safari to access YouTube instead.